# на СТО" или ".... в СТО"?

Tags: управление

Здравствуйте!
как правильно выражаться:
 "акция проводится на СТО" или ".... в СТО"?

СТО - станция технического обслуживания, направление деятельности юридического лица,
например:
акция стартует в СТО ООО "Ремонт"
(вариант: акция стартует на СТО ООО "Ремонт")

Answer (score 1):

Правил единых и универсальных тут нет, с этими предлогами В и НА вечная путаница. Причем не только у наших современников, в XIX веке еще были в ходу формы типа "на театре", "в конюшне" и проч. Но это долго все разбирать, если ставить вопрос ребром, то сейчас однозначно говорят "на станции". Но вот насколько это распространяется на аббревиатуру - не совсем понятно. Такие сокращения обычно рассматриваются как самостоятельные слова и они могут иметь собственные правила предложного управления. Является ли СТО одним из таких слов, требующих особого предлога - сказать трудно, есть ьенденция к тому, но пока еще не ставшая очевидной.

Таким образом, на мой вкус безусловно правильно будет ***"на СТО"*** - в любой фразе, но и ***"в СТО"*** вряд ли стоит считать ошибкой.

Поэтому

Comment: behemothus 
спасибо!
выскажу и свое интуитивное мнение:
станция как стоянка, ареал концентрации профильных воможностей, - объект, часть  поверхности суши :), имеющая границы, некая плоскость, требующая предлага "на",
СТО в современном гражданском обороте - сервисный центр, специальное помещение, требующее предлога "в"

Comment: Логика понятна, но не могу сказать, что все так однозначно. И СТО не всеми понимается как "часть суши" - и сам этот факт ничего не доказывает. Вспомните хотя бы классическое *"Почему **на лугу**, но **в поле, в степи**?"*  Пока этот \вопрос не решен, никаких обобщений ждать не приходится.

Comment: behemothus, "Почему на лугу, но в поле, в степи?" хороший вопрос!

Comment: behemothus, "Почему на лугу, но в поле, в степи?" хороший вопрос! выскажу догадку: "на лугу" - указание места (признак ландшафта, плоскости), на поверхности которого произрастает корм, на  этой поверхности пасется скот, на этой поверхности пребывают и пастухи, "в поле, в степи" - указание места, являющегося природным объектом, имеющим трехмерное измерение (длина, ширина, высота)

Comment: Господь с вами, какое "трехмерное измерение" (сочетание-то какое!) у поля или степи? Хорошо, возьмите "на озере" и "в море, океане"(остров, например)  При этом "на море" в отдельных случаях тоже возможно. Нет, я думаю, бессмысленно искать закономерности там, где их заведомо нет. Точнее говоря, у наших далеких предков какая-то мотивация выбора предлога может и была, но полностью утрачена вместе с изменением языка и реалий окружающего мира. Взамен появляются какие-то новые, а с ними и попытки по-новому объяснить семантику слов, в частности - этих предлогов.

Comment: Но традиция-то сохранилась, не всегда понятная и непоследовательная, но она упорно сопротивляется такому переосмыслению.   То же, видимо, и с этим СТО.